# Python using data series as input function

Tags: python, matlab, function, numpy, io

I've created a timeseries data in matlab that is rather hard to describe as a function, and I'm wondering the best way to port that to Python. The problem being that the timer in python will rarely, if ever, take on the exact values of the data set. I'm fairly certain something like this would work:

```
#this is matlab code just to represent the data
t=linspace(t0,tf,samples);
dataseries;
input=timeseries(dataseries,t);

#python code
def f(timer):
  for i in range(0,len(t)):
    if timer>t[i] and timer<=t[i+1]:
      f=dataseries[i]
    else:
      pass

output=f(timer)
```

but I feel like that will be incredibly slow because it has to check through all of t every time the code block runs. Is there a simpler way to get this functionality? the following may be a bit faster but still seems dirty:

```
def f(timer):
  for i in range(0,len(t)):
    diff[i]=np.abs(timer-t[i])
  location=np.argmin(diff)
  f=dataseries[location]

output=f(timer)
```

I know I could approximate the function with a Fourier Series, but in this case, accuracy is important so I would prefer to keep the output as exact as possible. Is there a built-in function in Python for this?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**
As requested here is a full code instead of just pseudo-code. Using this code works but as predicted it is quite slow. my timeseries is 10274 points long. Each function call takes 0.015 seconds.

```
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

A=scipy.io.loadmat('data_for_python.mat')
time_series=A['t'][0]
unshaped_in=A['in'][0]
shaped_in=A['real_in'][0]

time0=datetime.datetime.now()

diff=np.ones(len(time_series))*50
print len(time_series)
def f(time):
    for i in range(0,len(time_series)):
        diff[i]=np.abs(timer-time_series[i])
    location=np.argmin(diff)
    f=shaped_in[location]
    return f

timer=0    
while(timer<15):
    timer=datetime.datetime.now()-time0
    timer=timer.total_seconds()
    t0=datetime.datetime.now()
    output=f(timer)
    t1=datetime.datetime.now()-t0
    print 'time:', timer
    print 'dt',t1.total_seconds()
    print 'output:', output
```

Comment: How are you assigning `timer` when you call your function `f()`?

Comment: Well, it was just pseudo-code so I left that out but I'll update it. Thanks for keeping me honest :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking at python's `bisect` module...there are several ways to do this depending on if/how you handle the exactly equal case.  The `bisect_left()` method returns the index of the array "to the right" of the specified value, assuming your time series array is strictly ordered.

```
import bisect
import numpy as np

def f(time):
    return bisect.bisect_left(time_series, time)

>>> time_series = np.array([0, 1, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0])
>>> bisect.bisect_left(time_series, 0.9)
1
>>> bisect.bisect_left(time_series, 1.0)  ## note the value when you are exactly equal to a time_series value
1
>>> bisect.bisect_left(time_series, 1.1)
2
>>> bisect.bisect_left(time_series, 1.4)
2
>>> bisect.bisect_left(time_series, 1.5)
2
>>> bisect.bisect_left(time_series, 1.500001)
3
```

As you can see, this generally gives you the right-hand endpoint for a value x, unless you have equality.  There are other methods that handle the endpoints differently, `bisect()` and `bisect_right()`, so I'd recommend reading the python docs if you're interested in that behavior.

If you want to use the left-hand index, just subtract one from the return value, and you can use that to index into another array if needed.  You will want to error check the result before using it though:

```
ind = bisect.bisect_left(time_series, time)
if (ind < 0) or not (time_series[ind-1] < time <= time_series[ind]):
     ## raise an error condition
```

Comment: This will do very nicely. Thanks for the help. I'll have to time it to see the difference in computational time between this and an updated version of the code above. I will post the results after.